# Cannot run function on divs created with ajax JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, function, jsonp

i am creating a few divs from some JSONP data that i am retrieving from a server. I am trying to run a simple jquery function to change the background image when the divs are clicked, however, nothing seems to be happening when i click them. My code looks like so;

```
success: function(data){
 console.log(data);
 for(aArray in data)  {
 var array = data[aArray];
 $("#first").append('<p>' + array.something + '</p>');
 $("#second").append('<div class="buttons btn"><p>' + array.something + '</p></div>');
 $("#third").append('<div class="buttons btn"><p>' + array.something + '</p></div>');
 $("#fourth").append('<div class="buttons btn"><p>' + array.something + '</p></div>');
 }
```

The code above displays the data as it should, however, when i try to attach a function to the buttons class nothing happens. Am i doing something wrong? If i put a div on the page and run the function, the background-image changes as it should. The following is my change bg function;

```
$(".buttons").click(function()   {
$(this).removeClass("buttons").addClass("buttonsDown");
});
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttons', function() { 
  $(this).removeClass("buttons").addClass("buttonsDown");
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and after a bit of research seems to be the one i am after. Many thanks for the info!

Comment: The code in your answer (post edit) is identical in functionality to the code in the question. If you're going to use `on()` you need to use the event delegation style, which is called on a non-dynamically generated element, and takes a selector for child elements that should trigger the callback function.

Comment: Sorry I changed `.live()` to `.on()` because `.live()` is deprecated and forgot a little how `.on()` works hope I am right now.

Answer (score 0):

To bind events to dynamically added elements, you should use  jQuery's `.on()` and pass the context like:

```
$('.buttons').on('click', function(evt) { 

      $(this).removeClass("buttons")
             .addClass("buttonsDown"); 
    });
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending the element dynamically you should use `on` or `delegate` for events to work on them.

Using `delegate()`

```
$(document).delegate('.buttons', 'click', function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("buttons").addClass("buttonsDown");
});
```

Using `on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttons', function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("buttons").addClass("buttonsDown");
});
```

References:

- `on()` - http://api.jquery.com/on/
- `delegate()` - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/